# PowerShell - Last Saved File - Want to narrow down to last 7 days

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the following code working as I want it to, but I want to advance it by adding in logic to only report on the files that are less than 7 days old. I am not sure if I can do it with this logic..

```
Remove-Item ("c:\temp\output.txt")
$Date = Get-Date
Write-Output $Date | Out-file 'c:\temp\output.txt' -Append

$word = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$word.Visible = $false #to prevent the document you open to show
$filename = "Test User"
$filelocation = "\\server\Storage\Applications\Employee Sheets\Test.xlsm"
$doc = $word.Workbooks.Open($filelocation, $false, $true) # open in read only mode 
Write-Host ‘Currently processing’ $filename ‘/ 1 out of 45’ 

$binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
Foreach($property in $doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties) {
try {
  $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("name",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
  if ($pn -eq "Last author") {
     $lastSavedBy = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
        }
  if ($pn -eq "Last Save Time") {
      $lastSavedTime = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null) 
        }
    }
catch { }
}
$doc.Close($false) 
$word.Quit()

$1 = "Last Saved By: " + $lastSavedBy
$2 = "Last Saved Date: " + $lastSavedTime

Write-Output "$filename $1 $2" | Out-file 'c:\temp\output.txt' -Append

Invoke-Item ('c:\temp\output.txt')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start simply, imagine you have a folder with files like this:

```
    Directory: C:\users\Stephen\Downloads


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        6/22/2016  11:05 AM          85638 GOINGSTATELESS (1).jpg
-a----        6/22/2016  11:03 AM          75529 GOINGSTATELESS.jpg
-a----        6/17/2016   9:45 PM         738880 JavaSetup8u91.exe
-a----        6/15/2016   2:08 PM           8390 CheckIfSCOM2012r2WasUpgradedToUR3.ps1
-a----        6/15/2016  12:01 PM        7811072 LWAPlugin64BitInstaller32.msi
-a----        6/15/2016  10:59 AM          45648 36491_SCOM_AppMonitoringPhase3_Change Order.docx
d-----         6/6/2016   3:27 PM                ffmpeg-20160531-git-a1953d4-win64-static
-a----         6/6/2016   3:24 PM       15201547 ffmpeg-20160531-git-a1953d4-win64-static.7z
d-----         6/6/2016   3:17 PM                dedication.tar
-a----         6/6/2016   2:18 PM       14344935 20160606_135011.mp4
```

As you can see, their ages (As defined by lastWriteTime) are all over the place, and only a few are less than a week old.

If I wanted to only get the files which have been access in the last week, I'd run this instead.

```
dir | Where LastAccessTime -ge ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))

    Directory: C:\users\Stephen\Downloads


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        6/22/2016  11:05 AM          85638 GOINGSTATELESS (1).jpg
-a----        6/22/2016  11:03 AM          75529 GOINGSTATELESS.jpg
-a----        6/17/2016   9:45 PM         738880 JavaSetup8u91.exe
```

You simply need to apply the same logic to your code, before you run your big code block there.  Narrow down the list of files like this, and I think you'll be well on your way.

```
  $LastWeekFiles =  dir | Where LastAccessTime -ge ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))
   ForEach ($file in $lastWeekFiles){

   #Insert your code here

   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time yesterday, it helped me out a lot. But I am getting caught up on the correct placement to get the excel files to open up. I am either getting them all to open up and not run through the code, or I get one to open up and it processes the rest of the run on that one file. See the code below. Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem.  Move the ForEach ($file in $lastWeekFiles) line up to the fifth line. It should be immediately after the line which begins $LastWeekFiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Remove-Item ("c:\temp\output.txt")
 $Date = Get-Date
 Write-Output $Date | Out-file 'c:\temp\output.txt' -Append
 $LastWeekFiles =  Get-ChildItem "\\server\Storage\Applications\"| Where LastWriteTime -ge ((Get-Date).AddHours(-58))
 $word = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
 $word.Visible = $false #to prevent the document you open to show

 $binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
 $doc = $word.Workbooks.Open("\\server\Storage\Applications\" + $file, $false, $true) # open in read only mode

 ForEach ($file in $lastWeekFiles){

 ForEach($property in $doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties){

 try{

 $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("name",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)

if ($pn -eq "Last author") {
 $lastSavedBy = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
    } 
if ($pn -eq "Last Save Time") {
  $lastSavedTime = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null) 

    }

}


 catch{}

 } 

 }

 $doc.Close($false) 
$word.Quit()
```